# Is it possible to manage the content from a Facebook Comment box on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph

I've added `fb-comments` to my website and some users are posting very unwanted content on it. How can I remove them for all the other visitors? I can remove them/block them for me but can't hide them permanently for others.

Thanks for any kind of tips.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple methods for dealing with unwanted comments, and all of the methods are what Facebook calls "moderation." You must configure some things on your Facebook App page and on your webpage so that you can use the various tools.

I would start with the FAQ section on this [Facebook Developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments), and find the combination of tools that you like the best.

Comment: Any more details about the `moderation` implementation? Thanks!

Comment: The link Hunter Hogan provided is perfectly fine. The info you are looking for is a tad bit scroll down on the page in the FAQ section: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#faq and is called "How can I moderate my comments plugins?"